# Cloned Ubuntu won't launch without original drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, drive, clone

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on a partition of an external HDD, with bootloader placed in my sata SSD /dev/sda (Win10)

I wanted to clone the linux system for use on another pc, I succeeded in cloning but grub was broken/not installed properly, ran boot-repair, got that sorted and now I've run into another issue that I can't seem to find anywhere else.

I plugged out my SSD and EHDD, attempted to boot from the usb drive I cloned into, grub appears, I choose Ubuntu, and it gets stuck at "Starting Up"(Grub Legacy) or a Black Screen with flashing underscore(Grub2). The second I plug in my EHDD, the system boots and I'm running linux off my USB and I can plug my EHDD out.

Boot Log (I plug EHDD in at 105): https://paste.ubuntu.com/23616981/

Boot Repair Info Log: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23618410/

USB's UUID is 917cebdf-ce75-4113-a8cf-0d9c999d1910 , EHDD has a different one.

**EDIT:**(1 Month Later) I have quite literally POINTED out that I have changed the UUIDs, but apparently some people choose to be ignorant and mark this as a duplicate.

For those who may run into the issue I have in the future, please thank those that marked this as a duplicate as I sincerely doubt anybody will click this question now. I have yet to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: I stated my USB drive's UUID and posted a Boot Repair log that shows grub.cfg and fstab, I believe all the UUIDs are correct.

Comment: Can you post the output of cat /etc/fstab

Comment: It's in the second pastebin link under "sda1/etc/fstab"